# NodeJS & mustache: how to get partials working?

Tags: node.js, mustache

I want to use mustache with node, but for some reason partials won't work: I've created 2 files, `app.js` and `test.mustache`, both in the same directory. Using a `package.json` file and npm I've installed the latest version of mustache for this project. The files look like this:

app.js:

```
var mus = require('mustache');
console.log(mus.render('test.mustache: {{>test}}'));
```

test.mustache:

```
This is a test
```

If I run `node app.js` I expect to get the following output: `test.mustache: This is a test`, but instead I just get: `test.mustache:`.

Other mustache tags do work as expected, and even the vows test of mustache doesn't report any errors.

What should I do to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Try putting a space after the `>`

Comment: @murgatroid99 - I've already tried that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using node-inspector I've debugged the above application with Mustache. It turns out that Mustache doesn't automatically include the partial files, in contrary to what the [manual](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) implies (scroll down to partials). Instead you'll always need to provide the partials manually as the third argument to the render method.

Comment: The document you're looking at is the Mustache spec; different implementations work slightly differently, depending on what makes sense for that environment. In this case, the [documentation for this implementation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#partials) says, "In mustache.js an object of partials may be passed as the third argument to Mustache.render. The object should be keyed by the name of the partial, and its value should be the partial text."

Comment: @BrandonTilley - I've seen that documentation as well, however the above part of that documentation is exactly the same as the Mustache spec, and it's says may, not should. Therefore I thought that it just followed the specs, but if you supplied the partial argument it uses that instead of a new file. So the documentation is a little unclear about this.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this version of Consolidate.js supports partials: https://github.com/simov/consolidate.js

Consolidate makes it easy to use many templating engines inside Express.js